# Saving disparity map using OpenCV in PFM format

Tags: c++, opencv, disparity-mapping

I am trying to save a disparity map I got from stereo matching using cv::StereoSGBM in PFM format with [this code from github](https://github.com/antoinetlc/PFM_ReadWrite).

But the output has the same image repeated 4 times over horizontally instead.

[image: output]

Same disparity saved in .jpg format for reference - [image: .jpg image]

Why is this happening and how do I fix this?

**Code:**

PFMReadWrite.cpp

```
    bool savePFM(const cv::Mat image, const std::string filePath)
{
    //Open the file as binary!
    ofstream imageFile(filePath.c_str(), ios::out | ios::trunc | ios::binary);

    if(imageFile)
    {
        int width(image.cols), height(image.rows);
        int numberOfComponents(image.channels());

        //Write the type of the PFM file and ends by a line return
        char type[3];
        type[0] = 'P';
        type[2] = 0x0a;

        if(numberOfComponents == 3)
        {
            type[1] = 'F';
        }
        else if(numberOfComponents == 1)
        {
            type[1] = 'f';
        }

        imageFile << type[0] << type[1] << type[2];

        //Write the width and height and ends by a line return
        imageFile << width << " " << height << type[2];

        //Assumes little endian storage and ends with a line return 0x0a
        //Stores the type
        char byteOrder[10];
        byteOrder[0] = '-'; byteOrder[1] = '1'; byteOrder[2] = '.'; byteOrder[3] = '0';
        byteOrder[4] = '0'; byteOrder[5] = '0'; byteOrder[6] = '0'; byteOrder[7] = '0';
        byteOrder[8] = '0'; byteOrder[9] = 0x0a;

        for(int i = 0 ; i<10 ; ++i)
        {
            imageFile << byteOrder[i];
        }

        //Store the floating points RGB color upside down, left to right
        float* buffer = new float[numberOfComponents];

        for(int i = 0 ; i<height ; ++i)
        {
            for(int j = 0 ; j<width ; ++j)
            {
                if(numberOfComponents == 1)
                {
                    buffer[0] = image.at<float>(height-1-i,j);
                }
                else
                {
                    Vec3f color = image.at<Vec3f>(height-1-i,j);

                   //OpenCV stores as BGR
                    buffer[0] = color.val[2];
                    buffer[1] = color.val[1];
                    buffer[2] = color.val[0];
                }

                //Write the values
                imageFile.write((char *) buffer, numberOfComponents*sizeof(float));

            }
        }

        delete[] buffer;

        imageFile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cerr << "Could not open the file : " << filePath << endl;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

main.cpp

```
// Creating Disp map
stereomatching.computeDisparity(left, right, imgsize, disp);
    
// Writing PFM
cv::imwrite(outputpath + ".jpg", disp);
bool r = savePFM(disp, outputpath + ".pfm");
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question, `bool savePFM(const cv::Mat image, const std::string filePath)` + some small main function where you create the `cv::Mat` should be enough (not necessary to do `cv::StereoSGBM` if it can be reproduced with any image). Links to external sites (even github) might expire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for writing output PFM file in principle looks OK. However, you are accessing individual pixels with assumption that they are encoded as 3-channel 32-bit floating point values and that might not always be the case (usually they are 3-channel unsigned 8-bit integers, and the weird image in your question hints that there was some invalid out of bounds read). You can either check the `image.type()` and adjust your code accordingly, or convert your input matrix to desired `CV_32FC3` (3-channel 32-bit floating point pixels) type. To convert, you can either use the built-in opencv function

```
  cv::Mat image;
  originalInput.convertTo(image, CV_32FC3);
```

or if that doesn't work good enough (e.g. you would like to apply your custom 8bit -> 32bit mapping), just access the elements of the original image by

```
image.at<cv::Vec3b>(height - 1 - i, j);
```

and then apply some conversion from 8bit [0,255] to 32bit [0,1].

That's my best guess, because you didn't provide complete reproducible example.