# Why is the image data different when using Python and C++to normalize the image to 0 to 1.I use opencv

Tags: python, c++, opencv

this is my c++ code：

```
void writeImageDataToFile(const cv::Mat& image, const std::string& filePath) {
    std::ofstream outputFile(filePath);
    if (!outputFile.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "Failed to open file for writing: " << filePath << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    for (int channel = 0; channel < image.channels(); ++channel) {
        outputFile << "Channel " << channel << ":" << std::endl;
        for (int row = 0; row < image.rows; ++row) {
            for (int col = 0; col < image.cols; ++col) {
                outputFile << std::fixed << std::setprecision(6) << image.at<cv::Vec3f>(row, col)[channel] << " ";
            }
            outputFile << std::endl;
        }
        outputFile << std::endl;
    }

    outputFile.close();
}

int cntt = -1;
for (const auto& directory : directories) {
    std::vector<std::string> imagePaths = GetImagePaths(directory);

    
    for (const auto& imagePath : imagePaths) {
        cv::Mat image = cv::imread(imagePath);
        if (image.empty()) {
            std::cout << "Failed to read image: " << imagePath << std::endl;
            continue;
        }

        cntt++;
        cv::cvtColor(image, image, cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB); 
    

        cv::Mat resizedImage;
        cv::resize(image, resizedImage, cv::Size(32, 32));
        
        cv::Mat normalizedImage;
        resizedImage.convertTo(normalizedImage, CV_32F);

        cv::Scalar new_mean(0.9966, 0.9973, 0.9974);
        cv::Scalar new_std(0.0102, 0.0078, 0.0074);

    
        normalizedImage /= 255.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            normalizedImage.row(i) = (normalizedImage.row(i) - new_mean[i]) / new_std[i];
        }
        
    
        std::string outputFilePath = "normalized_image_data" + std::to_string(cntt) + ".txt";
        writeImageDataToFile(normalizedImage, outputFilePath);
        
        
    }
}
```

this is my python code :

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np

def write_image_data_to_file(image, file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'w') as output_file:
        for channel in range(image.shape[0]):
            output_file.write(f"Channel {channel}:\n")
            for row in range(image.shape[1]):
                for col in range(image.shape[2]):
                    output_file.write(f"{image[channel, row, col]:.6f} ")
                output_file.write("\n")
            output_file.write("\n")


input_folder = 'input0'  # Change to your input folder name
output_folder = 'output_folder3'  # Change to your desired output folder name
new_mean = [0.9966, 0.9973, 0.9974]
new_std = [0.0102, 0.0078, 0.0074]


if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
    os.makedirs(output_folder)


for filename in os.listdir(input_folder):
    if filename.endswith(".jpg"):
        image_path = os.path.join(input_folder, filename)

        
        image = cv2.imread(image_path)

        
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        image = cv2.resize(image, (32, 32))
        image = np.transpose(image, (2, 0, 1))

        
        image = (image / 255.0).astype(np.float32)
        for i in range(3):
            image[i] = (image[i] - new_mean[i]) / new_std[i]

        
        output_file_path = os.path.join(output_folder, filename.replace(".jpg", ".txt"))

        
        write_image_data_to_file(image, output_file_path)
```

but i can see,Txt file for printing image data using C++code:
normalized_image_data0.txt：("... "represents omitting the same)
image : 3x32x32

```
Channel 0:
0.333336 0.333336 0.333336 0.333336 0.333336 0.333336 0.333336 0.333336 0.333336 0.333336 0.333336 0.333336 ...(32 count)
0.346153 0.346153  ...
0.351349 0.351349 ...
1.000000 1.000000 ...
1.000000 1.000000 ...
1.000000 1.000000 ...
1.000000 1.000000 ...
1.000000 1.000000 ...
...

Channel 1:
0.333336 0.333336 0.333336 0.333336 0.333336 0.333336 0.333336 0.333336 0.333336 0.333336 0.333336 ...
0.346153 0.346153 ...
0.351349 0.351349 ...
1.000000 1.000000 ...
1.000000 1.000000 ...
1.000000 1.000000 ...
...
1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 0.980392 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 
1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 0.956863 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 0.992157 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 
1.000000 1.000000 ...
1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 0.992157 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 
1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 0.996078 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 
...

Channel 2:
0.333336 0.333336 ...
0.346153 0.346153 ...
0.351349 0.351349...
1.000000 1.000000 ...
1.000000 1.000000 ...
...
1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 0.992157 0.988235 0.980392 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 
1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 0.792157 0.988235 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 0.984314 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 
...
```

The txt file for printing image data using Python code:

```
Channel 0:
0.333336 0.333336 ...
0.333336 0.333336 ...
0.333336 0.333336 ...
...

Channel 1:
0.346150 0.346150 ...
0.346150 0.346150 ...
...
Channel 2:
0.351353 0.351353 ...
0.351353 0.351353 ...
...
```

The image data is completely different. Why?
I now need to ensure that the pre processed images in C++opencv are the same as those in Python opencv.This is my ultimate goal.This is the original image 0.jgp corresponding to 0.txt

[image]

Comment: Have you tried subtracting the arrays generated from each method? there could be rounding errors due to float vs double (I can't find which type you're using in C++ but numpy is float). Try to gather statistics on the average pixel delta to see if the error is acceptable or not

Comment: looks like your dimensions are somewhat transposed. What is first channel in python output seems to be first row of first channel in the c++ output

Comment: Can you show what is your `image.type()` in C++ code? Looks like something similar to [this situation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77409541/4165552)